# Cannot Import VPN connection

Tags: 12.04, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

Since 12.04 I cannot connect to my VPN. my ovpn file is the following

http://email.uoa.gr/help/download/vpn/edunet.ovpn

When I try to import the VPN file i get the following error

> The file 'edunet.ovpn' could not be read or does not contain
>   recognized VPN connection information
>
> Error: unknown PPTP file extension.

Is there any way arround this error? I have already installed network-manager-openvpn

Answer (score 42, accepted):

My problem was that **network-manager-openvpn-gnome** was not installed, (weird because I though it would get installed automatically after installing network-manager-openvpn). I installed it and everything was fine.

So, to all people having the same problem make sure that

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```

after installing, restart the networking service, e.g. by executing

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Comment: I have it installed and it doesn't help, at least on 18.04.

Comment: For ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 and newer use systemctl instead...

```systemctl restart NetworkManager```

Answer (score 5):

My own experience of successful VPN connection establishing on Ubuntu 14.04

Our admin gave me 3 files to install them into openVPN for Windows 7: *.ovpn, *.crt, *.key

1. Execute the following commands in your Ubuntu terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome

   sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc

   sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
   ```
2. Open "Network Connections" window (VPN Connections -> Configure VPN)
3. Press "ADD" button, click on drop-down menu and pick "Import a saved VPN configuration", press Create button.
4. In "Select File to import" choose your "*.ovpn" file.
5. In "Editing ...your *.ovpn file name..." window enter your username and password for vpn. Make sure that a *.crt file appeared in CA Certificate field.
6. Open "IPv4 Settings" panel and choose "Automatic (VPN) addresses only".
7. Open "VPN" panel again and click "Advanced" button.
8. Open "TLS Authentication" panel and make sure your "*.key" appeared in "Key File" field. Press Ok button.
9. Press "Save" button in "Editing ...your *.ovpn file name..." window.
10. Your VPN connection should appear in "Network Connections" window.

That's all, I hope it helps. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem to ECII's. In my case **network-manager-vpnc-gnome** had to be installed first. To do so I typed in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
```

Answer (score 2):

When you import be sure that the following fields are populated:

1. user certificate
2. CA certificate
3. privacy key

Your save button will become visible.
This worked for me.

Comment: And then after i installed network-manager-openvpn-gnome I run into the problem of the grayed "Save" button, and I saw that the certificate was missing. I located it and everything worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is using KDE as the desktop manager, the right package to be installed may be  `network-manager-vpnc-kde`, if available:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc-kde
```