# openvpn: this is a generic configuration and cannot directly be used

Tags: 12.04, vpn, openvpn

I have experienced a problem.
I have installed **OpenVPN** AS on **VPS**.
Used `.ovpn` config with **OpenVPN** Connect on my Windows 7 desktop. Works fine.

When I tried to configure VPN connection on Ubuntu, I have experienced following errors:

1. via command line:

   ```
   sudo openvpn ~/Downloads/server-locked.ovpn
   this is a generic configuration and cannot directly be used
   ```
2. via network connections manager (which has icon placed on status bar, near time) -> VPN Connections - > Configure VPN -> Import

   I receive Cannot import VPN Connection:

   ```
   The file '.ovpn' could not be read or does not contain recognized VPN connection information
   Error: The file to import wasn't a valid OpenVPN client configuration..
   ```

what I already tried:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc-gnome
```

What I should to do to make it work with `*.ovpn` file?

Content of my server-locked.ovpn file

```
# Automatically generated OpenVPN client config file
# Generated on Sat Mar 29 11:51:42 2014 by main
# Define the profile name of this particular configuration file
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_PROFILE=.../Dynamic
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_DYNAMIC=1
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_CLI_PREF_ALLOW_WEB_IMPORT=True
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_CLI_PREF_ENABLE_CONNECT=True
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_CLI_PREF_ENABLE_XD_PROXY=True
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_WSHOST=...:443
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_WEB_CA_BUNDLE_START
# -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
# -----END CERTIFICATE-----
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_WEB_CA_BUNDLE_STOP
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_IS_OPENVPN_WEB_CA=1
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_ORGANIZATION=OpenVPN Technologies, Inc.
setenv FORWARD_COMPATIBLE 1
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_GENERIC=1

setenv GENERIC_CONFIG
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
## -----BEGIN RSA SIGNATURE-----
## DIGEST:sha256
## -----END RSA SIGNATURE-----
## -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
## -----END CERTIFICATE-----
## -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
## -----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Would need to see the contents of `server-locked.ovpn`. You should either remove any sensitive info and add the contents to your question, or ask a friend to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot Import VPN connection](http://askubuntu.com/questions/142865/cannot-import-vpn-connection)

Comment: I'm voting this question to be closed because [problem went away magically](http://askubuntu.com/a/441051/61218)

Answer (score 2):

Just download `client.ovpn` instead of `server-locked.ovpn` and all works fine for now via command line. Looks like magic, but works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to *edit / re-download* your OpenVPN configuration.

The reason is that the `server-locked.ovpn` you posted does not contain the address of your VPS. It should probably be on the line

```
# OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_WSHOST=...:443
```

So it looks like your current configuration file does not actually contain any settings and the message

```
this is a generic configuration and cannot directly be used
```

is an error message telling you that the problem is with your configuration.

Comment: I deleted IP adress from those lines OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_WSHOST=...:443 and  OVPN_ACCESS_SERVER_PROFILE=.../Dynamic as well as I deleted all hashes between BEGIN and END certificates before posting there

Comment: Ah, ok. In that case, please comment the line `setenv GENERIC_CONFIG` and try to run `openvpn` from the terminal again. This is guessing, but you might at least get a different error message...

Comment: Just download client.ovpn instead server-locked.ovpn and all works fine for now via command line.