# Setting up ProtonVPN for Ubuntu 17.10 not working. The interface on Ubuntu 17 is different on the tutorials and I'm not sure how to set this up

Tags: vpn, openvpn

The dialog window for ubuntu 17 looks like this:

[image]

I tried clicking the vpn add button and pick the .ovpn file and I get the following message:

[image]

How do you setup protonvpn for ubuntu 17? Also I tried doing it in the command line version and that didn't work neither as it just hangs.

Answer (score 1):

To get the terminal version working do the following:

I followed the following: [Cannot Import VPN connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/142865/cannot-import-vpn-connection)

In addition I also installed:

```
sudo apt install openresolv
```

Then I tried this:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 
ping google.com
```

If 8.8.8.8 works but google.com doesn't work that means its your dns. Which I then edited `/etc/resolv.conf` and changed the nameserver to 8.8.8.8

That solve my issue.

Get your IP with:

```
curl wtfismyip.com/json
```

---

To get the GUI one to work after doing the above for the command line. I did this for the GUI to work:

```
sudo apt install openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome -y
```

I rebooted and then you add a VPN option. This time you should see a OpenVPN option and not just P2TP option.