# How to automatically open and set a user and password from a ".ovpn" file?

Tags: network-manager, password, vpn, openvpn, autostart

I am using Open VPN to acces to a VPN network. I have my ".ovpn" file. Everytime I want to acces the VPN Network:

- I have to go to the "myfile.ovpn" folder and type:

sudo openvpn --config "myfile.ovpn"

- And then I have to type the user and password.

I am wondering if there is any way to do that process automatically, I mean:

- With a fast command, connect to my VPN network without going to the file, open the file and type the user and password.

Best

Answer (score 0):

You have not said what version/flavour of Ubuntu you are using but for Ubuntu 20.10 anyway you can open the settings GUI, select `Network` settings and add a vpn there by pressing the `+` button.

Choose `Import from file...` and select your .ovpn file and enter username/password.

Then the VPN can be enabled/disabled via the network settings or via the top-right system menu dropdown. Without re-entering password.

If you want the vpn to always be enabled you can run `nm-connection-editor` and edit the settings of your network connection (not vpn) to auto-connect to your vpn.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. With your method it doesn't works for me. it says "Cannot import VPN connection. The plugin does not support import cappability ". Using "sudo openvpn --config file.ovpn" it works. Do you have any idea which is the reason for that ? Best,

Comment: @PauAl the post I link below says to ensure certain packages are installed so I would try that first. I have only ever used files provided by nordVPN and never had issues myself. Try tailing system logs when you get the message to see if you can see any messages or errors https://askubuntu.com/questions/142865/cannot-import-vpn-connection

Comment: I have already installed all the packages. I even tried to modify the file ".ovpn" . It is not working...